# Why my first script in selenium is not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i am using Eclipse as IDE, Java 17,
Selenium 4.8.1 ,
ChromeDriver   111.0.5563.64
Chrome Browser  111.0.5563.65
I have set the paths as System Variables:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
C:\az\Chrome
C:\az\Selenium
```

In eclipse i have set as Java Build Path:

```
Modulepath: JRE System Library[Java 17]
Classpath:
chromediver.exe - C:\az\Chrome
selenium-java-4.8.1.jar - C:\az\Selenium
selenium-server-4.8.1.jar - C:\az\Selenium
```

This is my code :

```
package chromepackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ChromeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();

        ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        ops.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=0.0.0.0");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\az\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    }
}
```

And this is the error I get :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 40083

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Mar 19, 2023 12:46:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError

WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
```

I am trying to run my first script in Selenium + Java and a blank page appears.

Comment: Why the argument `--whitelisted-ips`? Try without both of the args.